# Which Actors Were Featured in Both Star Wars Trilogies?

Tags: star-wars, actors

Apart from the voice of Yoda, [Frank Oz](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000568/), have there been any other actors who played a role in both trilogies? I suppose [Hayden Christensen](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0159789/) counts, having been recently included in the Blu Ray version of Episode VI.

Comment: Hayden Christensen does not count. Let's just all pretend he wasn't in the prequels either.

Comment: Would people mind making this a CW?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When Lucas was talking about making three trilogies, he said that the droids (R2-D2 and C-3PO) were the only ones that would be in all three trilogies and in all nine movies (this was in the 70s, when he said there would be three trilogies).  He said the story was basically told through their eyes.

Excluding *The Clone Wars* (the movie and both animated series), here's the actors who were in both trilogies (but not always in all films):

[Anthony Daniels](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000355/) played C-3PO and [Kenny Baker](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0048652/) played R2-D2 in all six movies.

[Frank Oz](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000568/), as you have already mentioned, played Yoda's voice in five movies.

[Ian McDiarmid](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001519/) played Senator/Chancellor/Emperor Palpatine (and Darth Sidious) in 4 movies (Episodes I-III and VI) originally, but was [dubbed in for Episode V later](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001519/otherworks).  So you could say he was in four of the movies when they were originally released, but is currently in 5 of the movies.

Also, as you pointed out, [James Earl Jones](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000469/) was in four films as Vader's voice, and when [Hayden Christensen](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0159789/) was added in to Episode VI (replacing [Sebastian Shaw](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0789970/) at the end), he was in three films.

[While some say Greedo showed up in 2 films](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Greedo#Portrayals), one in each trilogy, he was played by different actors in Episode I and Episode IV.

If the Special Editions are taken into account [Temuera Morrison](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0607325/) is in 3 films, playing Jango Fett and his clones in Episodes II and III and voicing Boba Fett in the Special Edition of Episode V.

Comment: What 9 movies? There were only two trilogies.

Comment: While he was still working on the original trilogy, Lucas was talking about making 3 trilogies and had talked with Mark Hamill about appearing as an older and wiser Luke Skywalker briefly in the sequel trilogy.  Now, with his tendency to retcon memory and fact as well as his movies, he claims there never was an intent to make a third trilogy.

Comment: Christensen replaced Sebastion Shaw, not Jones.

Comment: In fact there never was an intention to make more than one. Lucas is one big retcon

Comment: @horatio: True, but it makes my brain hurt when I remember reading interviews and articles in magazines like Starlog in the 70s and 80s where there was talk of that.  So I guess my memory is faulty and Lucas forgot to take care of that!

Comment: @horatio I watched an interview in about 1979 on TV where Lucas mentioned plans to shoot 9 episodes, and that he had some ideas down on paper for where the big plot was going. He did, by the time Empire was released, have an idea of fleshing it out beyond three movies, and the script of ESB is very clear that it is left hanging for a resolution in RotJ. There is no evidence that there was anything more than the vaguest ideas, but Lucas himself was talking about 9 episodes before ESB was out.

Comment: @aramis: this is after the first one made money for him, and he was able to actually fund his own madness. There is so much retcon in the 2nd two movies it is pretty obvious that he was amending the story, not continuing it. He is a baldface liar in the interviews, and there is no reason to suspect he became this way only at the release of the dvd special edition with Twice the Bantha Poodoo.

Comment: @horatio: I don't know if you remember when the original trilogy came out, but I remember reading and watching every single thing that came out about _Star Wars_ during that era and watching it all unfold.  There is more than enough that came out during that time period to show that he had planned multiple stories from the start.  Carrie Fisher, Mark Hamill, and Gary Kurtz, to name some people, have supported him on this.  Also, a .pdf that you can still find on the web called _The Secret History of Star Wars_ does an excellent job of documenting Lucas' writing progress from the very start.

Comment: I saw the first one 11 times in the theater. I am fairly familiar with the materials and his extended borrowings from Herbert, Kurusowa etc.

Comment: The Time Magazine interview from 1977 has mention of the sequels throughout it, starting on page 3: http://www.rollingstone.com/movies/news/the-wizard-of-star-wars-20120504 - page 5 mentions retaining the actors.  For context, this was just after Star Wars opened in the US but before it opened overseas.

Answer (score 6):

What about [Chewbacca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chewbacca) played by Peter Mayhew, he was in III and IV-VI

Comment: Just rewatched episoded I-III. I thought about this too.

Answer (score 4):

You guys forgot Warwick Davis!

He played Wicket in Episode VI (in costume) and also had 4 (uncredited) appearances in Phantom Menace

> He had four brief uncredited appearances in The Phantom Menace—one as
>   W. Wald, the young Rodian friend of Anakin Skywalker; the other as
>   Weazel, one of the gamblers at the podrace. Davis also had a cameo as
>   a "Tatooine street trader", and doubled Yoda in some of his "walking"
>   scenes in Episode I

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The only characters to appear in both trilogies were Anakin Skywalker / Darth Vader, Obi-Wan Kenobi, The Emperor, R2-D2 and C-3PO, plus the <s>muppet</s> character Yoda.

The first two were played by other people, except the appearance of [Hayden Christensen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayden_Christensen) as you mention. [Ian McDiarmid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_McDiarmid#Star_Wars) played [Emperor Palpatine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palpatine) (as Kev's answer mentions).

You also mentioned [Yoda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda)'s voice ([Frank Oz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Oz)). On the subject of voices, [James Earl Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Earl_Jones) played [Darth Vader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darth_Vader)'s voice in both trilogies.

Finally, [Anthony Daniels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Daniels) played [C-3PO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-3PO) and [Kenny Baker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenny_Baker) played [R2-D2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R2-D2) in both trilogies.

Comment: All four films?

Comment: Well, there were six films but, no, not each person was in all six films. But you asked if they were in both **trilogies**. E.g. James Earl Jones was in Episodes 3 - 6 only.

Comment: Right, it was just the phrasing which didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @anthony-arnold: Oops, you're right, corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ian McDiarmid appears as the emperor in episodes I, II, III and VI in the original trilogy.
He is also in the amended version of episode V, but not the original theatrical version.

Comment: You're right, great observation! Hope you don't mind, I incorporated (read: stole) it into my answer to make one definitive answer.

Comment: @Kev: I switched 'IV' to 'VI'.  The Emperor wasn't in 'A New Hope', but I knew what'cha meant.

Answer (score 1):

The only actor whose face can be seen in both trilogies is Ian McDiarmid (1, 2, 3, 6 added later to 5).

[image: Ian McDiarmid]

Another actor whose face can be seen is Hayden Christensen who was digitally added later into Ep. 6.

[image: Hayden Christensen]

Others that appear on screen but with a body costume, are Peter Mayhew (3, 4, 5, 6), Anthony Daniels (all) and Kenny Baker (all).

[image: Peter Mayhew as Chewbacca]

[image: Anthony Daniels and Kenny Baker as C3P0 and R2D2]

And the actors that contributed with their voice are; James Earl Jones (3, 4, 5, 6) and Frank Oz (1, 2, 3, 5, 6).

[image: Frank Oz as Yoda]
[image: James Earl Jones as Darth Vader]

Now that the cast for sequel trilogy is apparent, we might have some of these actors appear in 3 trilogies on top of obvious 4 appear in their 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember from seeing "The Empire strikes Back" preview before the initial Australian cinema release in 1980, the Emperor appeared at least in holographic communication with Darth Vader. Vader moved his Star Destroyer to where he could get better reception first. I don't know if that was Ian McDiarmid or another actor.

Comment: Originally, a different actor. The revised versions now show Ian McDiarmid.